# Zf2 form date element issue with different browsers

Tags: forms, browser, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a Zf2 form date element and i use it this way,

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
            'name' => 'releasedate',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Release Date'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'min' => '2012-01-01',
                'max' => '2020-01-01',
                'step' => '1', 
            )
        ));
```

So in chrome i get a date picker but not in safari or firefox ? i need to do any new configurations for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not all browsers supported input type date
http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Answer (score 1):

This is a Typical behavior, for the Date type, the reason for this is, Date Type is associated with HTML 5 Features , and all browsers dont support it, you have to use some thing different like , Jquery Calendar and then Mask date to (obviously after posting data)

```
 Zend\Form\Element\Date
```